# Regex to extract dates of various formats from URLs

Tags: r, regex, date, date-formatting

I need to extract the date from a dataframe of urls like these:

```
id | url
1 | https://www.infobae.com/tecno/2018/08/22/una-plataforma-argentina-entre-las-10-soluciones-de-big-data-mas-destacadas-del-ano/
2 | https://www.infobae.com/2014/08/03/1584584-que-es-data-lake-y-como-transforma-el-almacenamiento-datos/
3 | http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2018/01/09/economia1/ECON-02.html
4 | http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2017/12/01/economia1/ECON-01.html
5 | https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/08/16/noticia_0089.html
6 | https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/04/20/noticia_0090.html
7 | https://www.perfil.com/noticias/economia/supercomputadoras-para-sacarles-provecho-a-los-datos-20160409-0023.phtml
8 | https://www.mdzol.com/sociedad/100-cursos-online-gratuitos-sobre-profesiones-del-futuro-20170816-0035.html
9 | https://www.eldia.com/nota/2018-8-26-7-33-54--pueden-nuestros-datos-ponernos-en-serio-riesgo--revista-domingo
10 | https://www.letrap.com.ar/nota/2018-8-6-13-34-0-lula-eligio-a-su-vice-o-a-su-reemplazante
11 | https://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/270831-los-pacientes-deben-conocer-que-tipo-de-datos-usan-sus-medicos-coinciden-especialistas.html
12 | http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/271299-invierten-100-millones-en-plataforma-de-internet-de-las-cosas.html
13 | http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201308/30404-realizan-jornadas-sobre-tecnologia-para-gestion-de-datos.php
14 | http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201701/176163-inteligencia-artificial-lectura-de-diarios.html
```

these urls have the date in different formats:
links 1-6 use /yyyy/mm/dd/
links 7-8 use -yyyymmdd-
links 9-10 use /yyyy-m-d-
links 11-14 use /yyyymm/

Luckily, these are all numbers (no "Jar" instead of 1).

Is there a regex that could extract them all, or most of them?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/lT2RJo/2 nasty pattern, i know, but it works with all your examples.

Comment: but, to be clear, i would do multiple patterns to each site, like infobae, el litoral, cronista are using clearly the same pattern to do the urls.

Comment: Note all these dates start at yyyy, so you can locate the left-hand end of the date without even regex. Also, do we ignore the trailing `7-33-54` on `2018-8-26-7-33-54`?

Comment: Rui has a  solution without the heavyweight `stringi` / `stringr` / `tidyverse` deps (`lubridate` should be in everyone's toolbox IMO)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the following regular expression does what you want.

```
regex <- "\\d{8}|\\d{6}|\\d{4}[^\\d]{1}\\d{2}|\\d{4}[^\\d]{1}\\d{1,2}[^\\d]{1}\\d{1,2}"
regmatches(URLData$url, regexpr(regex, URLData$url))
# [1] "2018/08/22" "2014/08/03" "2018/01/09" "2017/12/01" "2017/08/16"
# [6] "2017/04/20" "20160409"   "20170816"   "2018-8-26"  "2018-8-6"  
#[11] "201804"     "201804"     "201308"     "201701"
```

**Edit.**

After reading the answer by @hrbrmstr I realized that it is probably better to coerce the results to class `Date`. I will use external package `lubridate` to do it.

```
d <- regmatches(URLData$url, regexpr(regex, URLData$url))
d[nchar(d) < 7] <- paste0(d[nchar(d) < 7], "01")
d <- lubridate::ymd(d)
d
# [1] "2018-08-22" "2014-08-03" "2018-01-09" "2017-12-01" "2017-08-16"
# [6] "2017-04-20" "2016-04-09" "2017-08-16" "2018-08-26" "2018-08-06"
#[11] "2018-04-01" "2018-04-01" "2013-08-01" "2017-01-01"
```

**Data in dput format.**

```
URLData <-
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 
13, 14), url = structure(c(10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 7L, 6L, 13L, 12L, 
8L, 11L, 14L, 5L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c(" http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2017/12/01/economia1/ECON-01.html", 
" http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2018/01/09/economia1/ECON-02.html", 
" http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201308/30404-realizan-jornadas-sobre-tecnologia-para-gestion-de-datos.php", 
" http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201701/176163-inteligencia-artificial-lectura-de-diarios.html                      ", 
" http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/271299-invierten-100-millones-en-plataforma-de-internet-de-las-cosas.html", 
" https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/04/20/noticia_0090.html", 
" https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/08/16/noticia_0089.html", 
" https://www.eldia.com/nota/2018-8-26-7-33-54--pueden-nuestros-datos-ponernos-en-serio-riesgo--revista-domingo", 
" https://www.infobae.com/2014/08/03/1584584-que-es-data-lake-y-como-transforma-el-almacenamiento-datos/", 
" https://www.infobae.com/tecno/2018/08/22/una-plataforma-argentina-entre-las-10-soluciones-de-big-data-mas-destacadas-del-ano/", 
" https://www.letrap.com.ar/nota/2018-8-6-13-34-0-lula-eligio-a-su-vice-o-a-su-reemplazante", 
" https://www.mdzol.com/sociedad/100-cursos-online-gratuitos-sobre-profesiones-del-futuro-20170816-0035.html", 
" https://www.perfil.com/noticias/economia/supercomputadoras-para-sacarles-provecho-a-los-datos-20160409-0023.phtml", 
" https://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/270831-los-pacientes-deben-conocer-que-tipo-de-datos-usan-sus-medicos-coinciden-especialistas.html"
), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```

Comment: @hrbrmstr Not cut and paste, just psychological, I guess. `[:digit:]` was used with negation of the class, I will edit and make it consistent.

Answer (score 1):

It may still be better to heed the advice of `lucas_7_94` if you know the dates will be "uniform" by URL prefix (but it's what you originally asked for):

```
library(stringi)
library(tidyverse)
```

Your data:

```
readLines(textConnection("https://www.infobae.com/tecno/2018/08/22/una-plataforma-argentina-entre-las-10-soluciones-de-big-data-mas-destacadas-del-ano/
https://www.infobae.com/2014/08/03/1584584-que-es-data-lake-y-como-transforma-el-almacenamiento-datos/
http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2018/01/09/economia1/ECON-02.html
http://www.ellitoral.com/index.php/diarios/2017/12/01/economia1/ECON-01.html
https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/08/16/noticia_0089.html
https://www.cronista.com/contenidos/2017/04/20/noticia_0090.html
https://www.perfil.com/noticias/economia/supercomputadoras-para-sacarles-provecho-a-los-datos-20160409-0023.phtml
https://www.mdzol.com/sociedad/100-cursos-online-gratuitos-sobre-profesiones-del-futuro-20170816-0035.html
https://www.eldia.com/nota/2018-8-26-7-33-54--pueden-nuestros-datos-ponernos-en-serio-riesgo--revista-domingo
https://www.letrap.com.ar/nota/2018-8-6-13-34-0-lula-eligio-a-su-vice-o-a-su-reemplazante
https://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/270831-los-pacientes-deben-conocer-que-tipo-de-datos-usan-sus-medicos-coinciden-especialistas.html
http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201804/271299-invierten-100-millones-en-plataforma-de-internet-de-las-cosas.html
http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201308/30404-realizan-jornadas-sobre-tecnologia-para-gestion-de-datos.php
http://www.telam.com.ar/notas/201701/176163-inteligencia-artificial-lectura-de-diarios.html")) -> urls
```

A readable, documented regex for your situation:

```
regex <- "
([[:digit:]]{4}/[[:digit:]]{2}/[[:digit:]]{2})|                 # 1st case - yyyy/mm/dd
([[:digit:]]{8})-[[:digit:]]|                                   # 2nd case - yyyymmdd-#
([[:digit:]]{4}-[[:digit:]]{1,2}-[[:digit:]]{1,2})-[[:digit:]]| # 3rd case - yyyy-m-d-#
([[:digit:]]{6})/[[:digit:]]                                    # 4th case - yyyymm/#"
```

and, then:

```
stri_match_first_regex(urls, regex, cg_missing = "", opts_regex = stri_opts_regex(comments = TRUE)) %>% 
  as_data_frame() %>% 
  select(-V1) %>% 
  unite(date, starts_with("V"), sep="") %>% 
  select(date)
  mutate(date = case_when(
    (nchar(date) == 10) & grepl("/", date) ~ as.Date(date, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
    (nchar(date) == 8) & grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$", date) ~ as.Date(date, format = "%Y%m%d"),
    (nchar(date) == 6) & grepl("^[[:digit:]]+$", date) ~ as.Date(sprintf("%s01", date), format = "%Y%m%d"),
    (grepl("-", date)) ~ stri_split_fixed(date, "-")[[1]] %>% sprintf("%02s", .) %>% paste0(collapse="-") %>% as.Date()
  ))
## # A tibble: 14 x 1
##    date      
##    <date>    
##  1 2018-08-22
##  2 2014-08-03
##  3 2018-01-09
##  4 2017-12-01
##  5 2017-08-16
##  6 2017-04-20
##  7 2016-04-09
##  8 2017-08-16
##  9 2018-08-22
## 10 2018-08-22
## 11 2018-04-01
## 12 2018-04-01
## 13 2013-08-01
## 14 2017-01-01
```